# Kotlin custom annotation, arguments

Tags: java, annotations, kotlin

I'm trying to create a custom annotation with an array of arguments but I get an error when trying to set the arguments in the constructor of the annotation. It says it is expecting a type annotation on the Role[], while, if i'm right the Role[] is the type. I looked up the syntax in the docs which can be found here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html. But this documentation only explains how I can use the annotation and not how to create one.

This is what my annotation code looks like:

```
@NameBinding
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Secured(vararg val value: Role[])
```

This is what my Role class looks like:

```
enum class Role {
   ADMIN, USER
}
```

and this is how I want to use it:

```
@Secured(Role.ADMIN, Role.USER)
```

I tried looking for any examples on how to create annotations in Kotlin but I can't seem to find any weirdly. Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: `vararg` **and** an array?  Also, that `[]` syntax is not how you declare an array type in Kotlin.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I forgot to delete vararg. and I thought the `[]` syntax did work. So I should do it with `Array<Role>`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following compiles:

```
enum class Role { ADMIN, USER }

annotation class Secured(vararg val value: Role)

@Secured(Role.ADMIN, Role.USER)
fun foo() {}
```

As does this:

```
enum class Role { ADMIN, USER }

annotation class Secured(val value: Array<Role>)

@Secured([Role.ADMIN, Role.USER])
fun foo() {}
```

They compile to the same bytecode, but Kotlin demands that you use slightly different syntax to instantiate the annotation.

Comment: Is it possible here to manipulate the value being sent in? I am trying to do a similar thing but instead of secured, I am trying to mask the value of of some fields. is it possible to override the toString function in the annotation class?